# How to run a method every time a TabItem is selected, in an MVVM application using Prism

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I have been trying to implement this for a while and haven't been able to do it so far, despite having the feeling that this should be something easy.

The difficulty comes from the fact that I have implemented a WPF application using the MVVM pattern. Now, this is my first attempt at both the pattern and the framework, so it is almost guaranteed that I have made mistakes while trying to follow the MVVM guidelines.

**My implementation**

I have three Views with their respective ViewModels (wired using Prism's `AutoWireViewModel` method). The `MainView` has a `TabControl` with two `TabItem`s, each of witch contains a `Frame` container with the `Source` set to one of the other two `View`s. The following code is an excerpt of the `MainView`:

```
<TabControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
    <TabItem Header="Test">
        <!--TestView-->
        <Frame Source="View1.xaml"/>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Results">
        <!--ResultsView-->
        <Frame Source="View2.xaml"/>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

**My problem**

Every time that someone changes to a specific `TabItem`, I would like to run a method that updates one of the WPF controls included in that `View`. The method is already implemented and bound to a `Button`, but ideally, no button should be necessary, I would like to have some kind of `Event` to make this happen.

*I appreciate all the help in advance.*

Comment: Can you please post the `xaml`? and one of the `ViewModels`?

Comment: Where is the method defined? In the view or the view model?

Comment: @3xGuy I have added the `xaml` code but the ViewModel code is quite long. What exactly would you like?

Comment: thank you, I will look into it give me a few.

Comment: @mm8 The method is defined in the ViewModel

Comment: @mm8 Yes, I have bound to the `Button`'s `Command` property a `DelegateCommand` (Prism) defined in my ViewModel.

Comment: The tabcontrol is a type of selector. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tabcontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396  When you choose a tabitem you are making an item selected.  You could bind the selecteditem to a property in your viewmodel and act in the setter for that. You can also bind and template to produce the tabitems.

Comment: Seeing as you have frames then I guess this is because you are using pages. Rarely a good idea, it's usually better to go with usercontrols. You could just put the usercontrol straight in the tabitem as well then.

Comment: @Andy I can easily change my Views to `UserControl`s. Would you mind elaborating a bit on why it's a bad idea to use `Page`s?

Comment: Contentcontrol and usercontrols is the usual way to work because they're lighter weight and more flexible.  Pages were invented in the early days of wpf when they intended it to be used in a browser as well as on a desktop or with a browser like experience. Rarely a good plan.  They are limiting in that you can only put them in frames. Frames are a relatively high overhead container due to their journal. If you're not going to use that journal facility then they're just all overhead compared to a content control. Frames also have some other rather subtle effects which are often unwanted.

Comment: @Andy Thank you :) I have switched to `UserControl`s  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate all of your input, but I found an alternative solution. Given the information given by @mm8, I took advantage of the `Loaded` event but in a way that does not require any code in the code behind.

**My solution**

In the `View` which I would like to give this ability to execute a method every time the user selects the `TabItem` that contains it, I added the following code:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OnLoadedCommand}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

And then simply implemented a `DelegateCommand` called `OnLoadedCommand` in the `View`'s respective `ViewModel`. Inside that command I call my desired method.

*Please comment if you spot anything wrong with this approach! I chose to try this since it required the least amount of changes to my code, but I may be missing some vital information regarding problems the solution may cause.*

Comment: If you need/want a tab control (as opposed to a region you navigate manually), this is definitely the way to go.

Comment: This will invoke the command each time the tab is selected. If that's not an issue, you could use an interaction trigger in the XAML. It's no violation of the MVVM pattern to execute the command programmatically from the code-behind of the view though. MVVM is *not* about eliminating *view* related code from the views. It's about separation of concerns.

Answer (score 1):

You could for example handle the `Loaded` event of the `Page` to either call a method or invoke a command of the view model once the view has been loaded initially:

```
public partial class View2 : Page
{
    public View2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += View2_Loaded;
    }

    private void View2_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var viewModel = DataContext as ViewModel2;
        if (viewModel != null)
            viewModel.YourCommand.Execute(null);
        Loaded -= View2_Loaded;
    }
}
```

The other option would be handle this in the `MainViewModel`. You bind the `SelectedItem` property of the `TabControl` to a property of the `MainViewModel` and set this property to an instance of either `ViewModel2` or `ViewModel2`, depending on what kind of view you want to display.

You could then call any method or invoked any command you want on these. But this is another story and then you shouldn't hardcode the `TabItems` in the view and use `Frame` elements to display `Pages`. Please take a look here for an example:

[Selecting TabItem in TabControl from ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45934828/selecting-tabitem-in-tabcontrol-from-viewmodel/45937167#45937167)

Comment: Hey Magnus. I'm not so sure the page will load again second time you select a tabitem. I've rarely used pages though.

Comment: @Andy: If you pay attention to my sample code, you see that I actually unhook the event handler when the Loaded event occurs. This means that the command will only invoked once, when the tab is selected the first time. If you want to invoke the command each time the tab is selected, you could simply remove this line of code. And yes, this should work as the TabControl actually unloads a tab that is deselected and then reloads it when it's selected again.

Comment: This seems like a good solution, being quite simple. But since this is done in the code behind, doesn't it break the MVVM pattern? Your comment stating that "TabControl actually unloads a tab that is deselected and then reloads it when it's selected again" is very useful, thank you :)

Comment: @r_laezza: This doesn't break the MVVM pattern. The code-behind of the view belongs to the same class as the XAML so whether you are executing the command from the code-behind or XAML doesn't matter. Doing this in the code-behing lets you unsubcribe from the event handler once the command has been invoked once.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so What I have done is Create a Custom Tab Control. I will write out step by step instructions for this, and then you can add edit to it.

1. Right click on your solution select add new project
2. Search For Custom Control Library
3. High Light the name of the class that comes up, and right click rename it to what ever you want I named it `MyTabControl.`
4. Add Prism.Wpf to the new project
5. Add a reference to the new project to where ever your going to need it. I needed to add to just the main application, but if you have a separate project that only has views then you will need to add it to that too.
6. Inherit your Custom Control From `TabControl`  Like:

   public class MyTabControl : TabControl
7. You will notice that there is a Themes folder in the project you will need to open the `Generic.xaml` and edit it. it should look like:

   `TargetType="{x:Type local:MyTabControl}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TabControl}}"` for some reason this will not let me show the style tags but they will need to be in there as well
8. Please review this code I got this from [Add A Command To Custom Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-implement-icommandsource)

   ```
   public class MyTabControl : TabControl
    {
        static MyTabControl()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyTabControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyTabControl)));
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TabChangedCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "TabChangedCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(MyTabControl), 
            new PropertyMetadata((ICommand)null,
            new PropertyChangedCallback(CommandCallBack)));

        private static void CommandCallBack(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var myTabControl = (MyTabControl)d;
            myTabControl.HookupCommands((ICommand) e.OldValue, (ICommand) e.NewValue);
        }

        private void HookupCommands(ICommand oldValue, ICommand newValue)
        {
           if (oldValue != null)
            {
                RemoveCommand(oldValue, oldValue);
            }
            AddCommand(oldValue, oldValue);
        }

        private void AddCommand(ICommand oldValue, ICommand newCommand)
        {
            EventHandler handler = new EventHandler(CanExecuteChanged);
            var canExecuteChangedHandler = handler;
            if (newCommand != null)
            {
                newCommand.CanExecuteChanged += canExecuteChangedHandler;
            }

        }

        private void CanExecuteChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.TabChangedCommand != null)
            {
                if (TabChangedCommand.CanExecute(null))
                {
                    this.IsEnabled = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.IsEnabled = false;
                }
            }
        }

        private void RemoveCommand(ICommand oldCommand, ICommand newCommand)
        {
            EventHandler handler = CanExecuteChanged;
            oldCommand.CanExecuteChanged -= handler;
        }

        public ICommand TabChangedCommand
        {
            get { return (ICommand) GetValue(TabChangedCommandProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TabChangedCommandProperty, value); }
        }


        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();
            this.SelectionChanged += OnSelectionChanged;
        }

        private void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (TabChangedCommand != null)
            {
                TabChangedCommand.Execute(null);
            }
        }
        }
   ```

you will need to add the name space in your window or usercontrol like:

```
xmlns:wpfCustomControlLibrary1="clr-namespace:WpfCustomControlLibrary1;assembly=WpfCustomControlLibrary1"
```

and here is your control:

```
    <wpfCustomControlLibrary1:MyTabControl TabChangedCommand="{Binding TabChangedCommand}">
        <TabItem Header="View A"></TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="View B"></TabItem>
    </wpfCustomControlLibrary1:MyTabControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd approach this sort of requirement:
View:

```
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWIndowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <TabControl Name="tc" ItemsSource="{Binding vms}">
            <TabControl.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:uc1vm}">
                    <local:UserControl1/>
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:uc2vm}">
                    <local:UserControl2/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.Resources>
            <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding TabHeading}"/>
                </Style>
            </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

When it has a uc1vm it will be templated into usercontrol1 in the view.
I'm binding to a collection of viewmodels which all implement an interface so I know for sure I can cast to that and call a method.

Main viewmodel for window:

```
    private IDoSomething selectedVM;

    public IDoSomething SelectedVM
    {
        get { return selectedVM; }
        set
        {
            selectedVM = value;
            selectedVM.doit();
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<IDoSomething> vms { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<IDoSomething>
    {   new uc1vm(),
        new uc2vm()
    };

    public MainWIndowViewModel()
    {

    }
```

When a tab is selected, the setter for selected item will be passed the new value. Cast that and call the method.

My interface is very simple, since this is just illustrative:

```
public interface IDoSomething
{
    void doit();
}
```

An example viewmodel, which is again just illustrative and doesn't do much:

```
public class uc1vm : IDoSomething
{
    public string TabHeading { get; set; } = "Uc1";
    public void doit()
    {
       // Your code goes here
    }
}
```